# php pull webpage data

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
 $pullurl = 'http://akroncanton.craigslist.org/jjj/';
 $contents = file_get_contents($pullurl);
 $result = preg_split('/<\/p>/',$contents);
 print_r($result); 
  ?>
```

So I was able to put that together after talking with some people yesterday basically what this dose is pull some data from a craigslist website.

And then divide every post people have published into $results 1 - whatever

The next step im looking to complete is to make it so it will recognize A title. Another words im thinking something along the lines of a while loop or do until you have ran all the results

Another words im looking to make it so

```
Do
if ($Results[2] *contains* 'Morage') {
echo '***HERE***';
}
until $Results[1-whatever ran]
```

im not to sure how to properly write this as I have said im new to this php thing all the help given is really appreciaite and I have tried searching im just lost and could really use some help

Comment: What is `$Results` and 'whatever ran'?

Comment: look at the code up top Results is what is pulled from the site and im not sure how to define a variable for how many there are look at the code up top and you will see.

Comment: Do you want to use `foreach ($results)`?  That will iterate over the list of results.

Comment: at the bottom of your craiglist page there is a RSS feed link. Use that instead of scraping the pages.

Comment: `$Results` is not the same as `$result`, because PHP is case-sensitive and plural-sensitive.

Comment: You generally shouldn't use regexp to process HTML, there are libraries for parsing HTML and XML.

Comment: Scraping data from Craiglist is against their Terms of Service and can wind up in court as they have [done](http://gigaom.com/2012/07/24/craigslist-sues-competitor-padmapper-over-listings/) before. Just giving you a friendly heads up.

Comment: Already have approval but thank you cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scrape a webpage, you should try [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) or [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). They are just like jQuery's $ function. They will give you the ease of usage rather than trying to finding and splitting the HTML tags by yourself.